# CSS: nowrap div's children divs going crazy when added content

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a layout where I have a Div that gets added its content in a dynamic way. I want this "parent" div to have a fixed height and when content its added the div grows horizontally as needed.

This is the test HTML I made to isolate the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:700px;overflow:auto">
    <div class="anio">
      <div class = "semestre">
        <div class="floater"></div>
        <div class="floater"></div>
        <div class="floater"></div>
        <div class="floater"></div>
        <div class="floater"></div>
        <div class="floater"></div>
        <div class="floater"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here i have 7 `class=floater` divs that go into the `class=semestre` container div which is supposed to grow horizontally as I add more `class=floater` divs. all of this goes into a fixed width div with `overflow-x:auto`.

after some fighting with the css i managed the following:

```
div.floater { 
    margin: 4px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 82px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block; /*this to make the floaters go horizontal*/
}
div.semestre{  
    white-space: nowrap; /* this avoid the floater overflowing under the parent div*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-width:98%;

}
div.anio{
    margin : 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-width:98%;

}
```

So this worked..kind of.. the `class=floater` divs go horizontal and cause the activation of the `overflow-x` on the outermost div, but the container divs that contain the `class=floater` div don't grow as i think the should (this can be seen by the borders not growing). After googling I found some proposed solutions like adding `width:auto` on top of the `min-width:` css property or floating them, but none worked. This is a minor issue since the borders are just for formatting.

The mayor problem I'm having is when I try to add content to the `class=floater` divs they just go CRAZY and won't stay where they should( when they had no content). i tried reverting the `white-space:nowrap` by adding `white-space:normal` to the floater class but that didn't work. After that I just went berserk and started trying random stuff and managed to fix my first problem but the I forgot what I did and went back to step 1  D:.

To be honest I'm very new to html/css and I'm learning by doing. So if this question has been already asked/answered believe me that I searched for it. Also excuse my English, doing my best.

Thank you for your time.

edit:
By request, the fiddle :D http://jsfiddle.net/UBYKy/1/
there you can see both of my problems.

edit 2: i believe i have found a solution to both problems. For the first one I solved it by adding `display: inline-block` to the parent divs and for the 2nd problem I added `vertical-lign:top` to the floater class css(as afshin suggested) and it works just fine. I hope this helps anyone having the same problem.

Comment: You better make a live example of your problem on http://jsfiddle.net and paste here the link, that way people would be more willing to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think you should use this**

```
div.floater { 
 vertical-align:top;
 margin: 4px;
 min-width:110px;
 width: auto;
 height: 82px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 display: inline-block; /*this to make the floaters go horizontal*/
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/UBYKy/2/)